Overview of positivity and maximum-principle-preserving numerical schemes for PDEs
I am interested in why and when positivity preserving numerical schemes for PDE are used.
Related: Which methods can ensure that physical quantities remain positive throughout a PDE simulation?
(but only about hyperbolic problems - I aim for a more general answer)
Why?
Many "academic" PDE problems, such as the Poisson, heat, wave, transport equations, lead to a-priori estimates that restrict the solutions without requiring explicit knowledge of them.
For example, the maximum principles for the Poisson and heat equations imply that the solution attains its maximum on the boundary or is constant. Physically, this is intuitive, as these equations model diffusion processes where heat should not accumulate locally to exceed boundary values. Thus, it is natural to construct numerical approximation methods that preserve properties like this maximum principle.
Additionally, in some PDEs, physical intuition suggests that solutions should remain strictly positive, even though this cannot always be proven a-priori. An example is mass or density conservation equations (e.g., the continuity equation). For problems involving compressible fluids, we expect the density to remain positive throughout the domain.
However, despite these important properties, I find that literature on positivity or monotonicity-preserving schemes seems limited, almost niche.

Question 1: Why is this not a more popular topic, if many physical applications would benefit from such schemes?

When/how?
As mentioned above, I am aware of when - physically speaking - one needs to take into account positivity or monotonicity or maximum-principle preserving schemes:

Positivity: the value of a variable is physically defined to be postive
Max. principle: the physical process always gives rise to variables being restricted to a certain range of values

But from a numerical perspective:

Question 2: Could you provide an overview of numerical schemes that preserve these properties when applied to specific problems? Alternatively, are there classes of schemes that inherently fail to preserve these properties? I am also happy with a reference to a book or a review article.

A particular technique
I encountered a specific technique for preserving the positivity of the density $\rho$ in a PDE problem. Instead of solving the equation for $\rho$ directly,
$$\partial_t \rho + \nabla\cdot (\mathbf{v}\rho)=0,$$
one can solve for the quantity $\bar \rho := \log (\rho)$ instead,
$$\partial_t \bar \rho + \nabla\cdot (\mathbf{v}\bar\rho)=0,$$
and then recover the density with $\rho = \exp(\bar\rho)$.
This method feels somewhat artificial to me—it's essentially applying a transformation and then reversing it, and we could presumably use any smooth map $\phi:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$ instead of the exponential function.

Question 3: Is there a strong physical or mathematical motivation for using this particular trick?


In CFD-type calculations it is common to see problems with "undershoots" when a positive-definite quantity goes to zero and below, which crashes the run because you'd need to take a log or sqrt etc. of that quantity. For those situations, there are various techniques, like adding an artificial source term maintaining a positive "floor" for the variable in question. Those positivity-preserving methods is something of similar nature; those are special techniques to avoid the undershoots.

I know that the $\log$/$\exp$ trick can be rigorously justified in a lot of PDE inverse problems applications. You can show that the $\log$ function still lies in some reasonable Sobolev space and using that parameterization makes the optimization unconstrained

Can you send me a reference that explains why this log/exp trick is rigorous? Furthermore, I would like to understand it intuitively - why should I believe that the simulation result resulting from an application of this trick is more valid that if I dont use it? Im asking this because applying the trick is not something that is part of the original problem formulation and its not something motivated by physics... We just somehow use it to "manually" fix our bad simulation result, right?

One approach is to reformulate the problem as a (possibly time-dependent) variational inequality or complementarity problem.
There are two levels at which you can look at this.
The first is for a problem like the heat equation or an advection-diffusion equation, where you know that the true solution satisfies a bounds constraint but you're using a discretization that might not give you a solution that stays within bounds.
You can then impose the bounds constraint on the discrete solution and see how good the results are.
Chang and Nakshatrala looked at this VI reformulation in this paper.
Then there are problems that do not have maximum/minimum principles as such but for which they need to be imposed because the solution physically cannot go below zero.
For example, this is the case for the advection of the thickness of a thin fluid film.
Ed Bueler wrote about discretizing real honest time-dependent VIs, with a view to modeling the dynamics of glaciers, in this paper.
Rob Kirby and I (mostly Rob) wrote this paper trying to extend the work of Chang and Nakshatrala to higher-order finite elements by using the Bernstein basis.
Unlike the usual Lagrange finite elements, if a function has positive coefficients in the Bernstein basis, then that function is positive, although the converse is not true.
Rob and I are doing more work on this especially as it shows up in geophysical problems.

Thanks.
Concerning VIs for discretizations that dont conserve the max-principle: This might work well, but seems a bit artificial at first. It might be, that your discretization produces a negative solution, and the VI enforces it to be zero - then you have not gained anything, right?
Concerning the second approach: would you say that problems that seek a physically positive variable but do not contain a maximum principle are "bad models" - maybe similar to ill-posed problems (that have more than one or no solution)?

No, I don't agree that these are bad models. The thickness of a film of fluid can't go negative. It can have negative sources of mass that would, without imposing the non-negativity constraint directly, result in a negative thickness. For example, a glacier subject to solar melting, or drainage of rainwater that then infiltrates into the subsurface. This speaks to the fact that the PDE itself is only part of the full specification of the physics problem. The Signorini problem is another good example -- nothing about the elasticity equations themselves prohibits crossing.

A rather old, but still highly-cited paper on this topic is "On Godunov-type methods near low densities" B Einfeldt, CD Munz, PL Roe, B Sjögreen
Journal of computational physics 92 (2), 273-295. Google Scholar lists more than 1100 citations of this paper, mostly related to some form of compressible flow solved with finite-volume or finite element methods. However, I quickly scanned through the citation list, and it seemed to be quite often cited by people with other interests in bound-preservation. It might be a good place for you to look.

Thanks a lot, this might serve as a replacement for a review article then!
